# delete stop words in a file in python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a file which consists of stop words (each in a new line) and another file (a corpus actually) which consists of a lot of sentences each in a new line. I have to delete the stop words in the corpus and return each line of that without stop words. I wrote a code but it just returns one sentence. (The language is Persian). How can fix it that it returns all of the sentences?

```
with open ("stopwords.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
   with open ("train.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as f2:
      for i in f1:
          for line in f2:
              if i in line:
                 line= line.replace(i, "")
with open ("NoStopWordsTrain.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as f3:
   f3.write (line)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Can you provide concrete examples of (partial) file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your last two lines of code are not in the for loop. You are iterating through the entire f2, line-by-line, and doing nothing with it. Then, after the last line, you write just that last line to f3. Instead, try:

```
with open("stopwords.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as stopfile:
    stopwords = stopfile.readlines() # make it into a convenient list
    print stopwords # just to check that this words
with open("train.txt", encoding = "utf-8") as trainfile:
    with open ("NoStopWordsTrain.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as newfile:
        for line in trainfile: # go through each line
            for word in stopwords: # go through and replace each word
                line= line.replace(word, "")
            newfile.write (line)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it sloved the problem. but now there is another problem that it doesn't delete the stop words. it returns all the sentences with out any change. but I can't see anything wrong with this code.

Comment: Earlier, I didn't look so closely at the code. I restructured it. See above. This should work better.

Comment: again the same problem. There is no change.

Comment: do you think if I use "split" for the train file, it works? if so how should I use it in the code? Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It seems that this issue has been solved though. If you have further problems, you should post those as a separate question with example input, output, and code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through both files, and write to the third one. [@Noam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836114/1708751) was right in that you had issues with the indentation of your last file open.

```
with open("stopwords.txt", encoding="utf-8") as sw, open("train.txt", encoding="utf-8") as train, open("NoStopWordsTrain.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as no_sw:
    stopwords = sw.readlines()
    no_sw.writelines(line + "\n" for line in train.readlines() if line not in stopwords)
```

This basically just writes all the lines in **train**, and filtering it if it's one of the stopwords.

If you think the `with open(...` line is too long, you can make use of Python's [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function to set *default* parameters.

```
from functools import partial
utfopen = partial(open, encoding="utf-8")

with utfopen("stopwords.txt") as sw, utfopen("train.txt") as train, utfopen("NoStopWordsTrain.txt", "w") as no_sw:
    #Rest of your code here
```